# Java networking IO server setup

Tags: java, networking, io, inputstream, bufferedreader

I want to play around with the Java networking I/O streams and API. I have a laptop and a PC on my network (I know the IP's to each of these devices) that connects through a Netgear DG834 router.

How would I configure my laptop as the "server" and my PC as the "client" when toying with java networking I/O streams.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for simple TCP communication using sockets. Take a look at this tutorial, it has it all for you to start: http://systembash.com/content/a-simple-java-tcp-server-and-tcp-client/

Basic idea is to have a **server** that listens at a certain port:

```
String clientSentence;          
String capitalizedSentence;          

//server listes at port number
ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(6789);          

//server is running forever...
while(true) {
    //... and is accepting connections
    Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();

    //receives string messages ...
    BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));             

    //... and sends messages
    DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());             
    clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine();             
    System.out.println("Received: " + clientSentence);             
    capitalizedSentence = clientSentence.toUpperCase() + '\n';              
    outToClient.writeBytes(capitalizedSentence);          
}
```

And the **client** should look like this:

```
String sentence= "this is a message";   
String modifiedSentence;   

//client opens a socket
Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 6789);   

DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());   
BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));   

//writes to the server
outToServer.writeBytes(sentence + '\n');   
modifiedSentence = inFromServer.readLine();   

System.out.println("FROM SERVER: " + modifiedSentence);   

//communication is finished, close the connection
clientSocket.close();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! very helpful.

Another question: Would I need to configure a special file naming convention on the "server"? Or is it just a matter of running both scripts from an IDE such as eclipse on both server and client?

Also for "Localhost" would I rather type in the IP of my laptop on my local network such as 192.168.0.3, would that work for the line:

Socket clientSocket = new Socket("192.168.0.3", 6789); //Open connection to Laptop on local network with IP 192.168.0.3 (server)

Comment: I don't really understand your question. But this can run on the same computer (i.e. localhost) or on different computers (then you provide an IP, e.g. 192.168.0.3). Port number is a must all the time.

Comment: Is there a specific folder / file naming convention for a java serverside application? Or do you just run the serverside code with an IDE on the server and it will automatically listen for the given port for any input. Same as the client, just run the application through an IDE such as Eclipse.

Comment: You don't even need Eclipse IDE. It's just this, it's this simple. No extra libraries, no nothing. This is pure java `java.net.*` package that comes with every JDK/JRE.

Answer (score 1):

A large part of Java networking is handled with Sockets.  The server is a ServerSocket.  The client is a Socket.  They connect and speak to each other.  That's where you should start, right at the Java API reading about these objects.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html

Answer (score 0):

You don't need 2 PC's to do this. You can do this in the same PC by configuring java processes to listen to 2 different ports.